# Post on Facebook Users Wall Using ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   string bodymessage = "This is test message description new";
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       CheckAuthorization();
   }

   private void CheckAuthorization()
   {
       string app_id = "726915170663586";
       string app_secret = "●●●●●●●●";
       string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";
       if (Request["code"] == null)
       {
           Response.Redirect(string.Format(
             "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
       }
       else
       {
           Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
           string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);
           HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
           using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
           {
              StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
              string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();
              foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
              {
                  tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                  token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
              }
           }
           string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
           var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
           client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = bodymessage });
       }
   }
}
```

I'm getting this error-

> Server Error in '/facebook' Application.
>
> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Source of Error:

```
(HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
```

Comment: Are you able to access the URL `"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}"` with filled query strings directly from browser?

Comment: It's showing - This page can’t be displayed

Comment: That is the issue. Make sure you're filling up valid query strings to get a response. Use Graph api documentation for reference.